# php composer with solarium library

Tags: php, composer-php, solarium

How am I supposed to use the Solarium Library https://packagist.org/packages/solarium/solarium

With PHP Composer? http://getcomposer.org/

- I ran

`composer require solarium/solarium`

- It installed properly then I added to my php file

`include_once './vendor/autoload.php';`

- Then how do I initialize the Autoloader? Before composer I would perform the following require and all the functions would then be available.

`require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Solarium/Autoloader.php');`

- I tried the following but it gives me `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Solarium\Autoloader on Solarium\Autoloader.php on line 53`

`new Solarium\Autoloader();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of an autoloader is that you **do not** have to require_once files before using them. Just call `new Solarium_Client();` after including the Composer autoload.php file, including it initializes the autoloader already.

Comment: Can I just download it from github and unzip it to web root and then just use require_once each time I want to use it instead of running composer to install it?