# Load and call external library at Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, composer-php

I can not figure out how to include and call external library at Kohana.

I am using Kohana, by using composer I have loaded **[tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth)** library to vendor folder. Composer said - autoloader file was created, but i have no idea - does Kohana loaded that autoloader file or not.

path to autoload -> **vendor/autoload.php**
path to library file -> **vendor/themattharris/tmhoauth/tmhOAuth.php**

1) Does I have to include something? If yes - what? autoloader file or file with library classes?
2) How to call some library's method from my controller?

Sorry I'm very new to Kohana.

Comment: First take a look to http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/autoloading. Your problem is similar to that described in http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9249/autoloader-problem/p1?

Comment: oh.. I got it.  
include_once './vendor/autoload.php';
$tmh = new tmhOAuth();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use `Kohana::find_file`:

```
require_once Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'autoload');
$tmh = new tmhOAuth();
```

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116416/php-composer-with-solarium-library?rq=1) helped me to figure this out

```
include_once './vendor/autoload.php';
$tmh = new tmhOAuth();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the code in `application/bootstrap.php` file which automatically includes the `vendor` folder (in latest Kohana version):

```
if (is_file(DOCROOT.'vendor/autoload.php'))
{
    require DOCROOT.'vendor/autoload.php';
}
```